# How to compile Java code after DXL import?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Using the Domino/Notes API, when importing DXL design elements (for example a LotusScript agent), you have the option to either compile LotusScript code at the time of import, with `DXLImporter.setCompileLotusScript(boolean flag)`, or leave the code uncompiled. If you leave the code uncompiled, then Domino will compile the code before first use. This is all fine with LotusScript.

Reading the API, I see no option for Java code. How can you compile Java code for use after importing from DXL programmatically?

(The question is not how you do it manually (like open every Java design element and save it to force compilation) but how it can be done programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to do something along the lines of what the ODP to NSF compiler does https://frostillic.us/blog/thread.xsp?thread=NSF+ODP+Tooling. For obvious reasons (OSGi dependencies, Java library accessibility, builder processes etc) it's not a trivial task.